# Postfix/Dovecot cannot receive email from external sources

Tags: postfix, dovecot

**HELP!** Haha. I recently was an idiot and foobared my server. I had a mail server running on it. On my new server, i am trying to set it back up and I cannot get it to work. I have almost the same exact configs from before. Everything works except I cannot receive emails from external sources. I can send emails find, I can receive forms from my own host, just not receive from another host. I have been searching around for couple of days just to get where I am. I just want to give up.

EDIT: Just to add, I am also able to connect through Outlook externally to receive my mail and send mail. If I send an email from myself to myself through Outlook, it works. It is not not my firewall or MX records.

The error I get when trying to send an email from an external source is

*Remote Server returned '554 5.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: Access denied'*

EDITEDIT: Also found this error:

*Mar 16 19:28:30 mydomain postfix/smtpd[28215]: connect from mail-ob0-f179.google.com[209.85.214.179]
Mar 16 19:28:31 mydomain postfix/smtpd[28215]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-ob0-f179.google.com[209.85.214.                                                                                                                                           179]: TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA (128/128 bits)
Mar 16 19:28:31 mydomain  postfix/smtpd[28215]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ob0-f179.google.com[209.85.214.179]: 554 5.7.1                                                                                                                                            : Recipient address rejected: Access denied; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=*

**postconf -n**

```
alias_database = $alias_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/bin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = .mail/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
mydomain = mydomain.net
myhostname = mail.mydomain.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains =
sample_directory = /etc/postfix/sample
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks, check_relay_domains
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /path/to/ca
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /path/to/cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /path/to/key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/spool/postfix/smtpd_tls_cache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**doveconf -n**

```
# 2.2.11: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.10.33-1-lts x86_64
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_location = maildir:~/.mail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </path/to/cert
ssl_key = </path/to/key
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}
```

Comment: Have you set an mx record in your dns?

Comment: Yes. This use to work on the old server and error even indicates that it is reaching the server, just bouncing off.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is you are using check_relay_domains - I believe this has been [deprecated](http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=107522979320218) (and [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/535843)) and you now use "reject_unauth_destination" for smtpd_recipient_restrictions

Comment: That would make sense, because I am on a new version of them now. I will test and let you know.

Comment: No dice. It does nothing. However I was able to find a new error I encountered to post. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but try adding reject_unauth_destination to the end of the smtpd_recipient_restrictions.  It worked for someone at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1277902.

Comment: I already tried that. When you mentioned it, I tried it with all three of the original, the three plus reject_unauth, the first two plus reject_unauth and I also tried commenting out the line all together.